# Indicial equation in Differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> The Indicial equation of $$t^2y''+ty'+(t^2-2)y=0$$ at $t=0$ is

What i try::

Let $y=t^r$ for $t>0$

Then $$r(r-1)t^r+rt^r+t^{r+2}-t^r=0$$

$$\bigg[r(r-1)+r-1\bigg]t^r+t^{r+2}=0$$

If $t^{r+2}$ not present in above equation. Then indicial equation is

$r(r-1)+r-1=0$.

But Here $t^{r+2}$ is present. So i did not understand How

can i find indicial equation in above question.

Help me please. Thanks

Comment: This means that $y = t^r$ is not a solution for any $r$. So you have to consider $y = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n t^n$ instead.

Comment: Nitpick : Shouldn't $(t^2-2)y$ yield $t^{r+2}-2t^r$ ?

Comment: Not sure how helpful this is, but the first equation is a Bessel equation with solution $y(t)=a\cdot J_2(t)+b\cdot Y_2(t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding indicial roots in an ODE, put $y=t^m$ and set the co-efficient of the least power of $t$ equal to zero.
$$t^2y''+ty'+(t^2-2)y=0 $$
$$ \implies m(m-1)t^m+mt^m+t^{m+2}-2t^m=0$$
The least powe of $t$ in above is $t^m$, let us set its coefficient equal to 0:
$m(m-1)=m-2=0 \implies m^2-2=0$. So for this ODE $m=\pm \sqrt{2},$
there are the indicial roots.

Comment: Thanks Dr. Zafar. For your solution. I Think it is $m^2-2=0$

Comment: Yes, thanks, you are right. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you're trying to use the Frobenius method. You have to use $$y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nt^{t+r}$$ and equate the coefficients of each power of t.